# Do we have a table of Expectations?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

I am aware of very good materials which have provided expositions on the expressions for various integrals and their results such as [this one](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/book/9780122947575). Are there any of such which derives expected values for various functions? I have made some preliminary search but haven't found any. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Almost every book has that ..Look at the last pages of this book :- Sheldon Ross First course in probability.

Comment: Thanks for sharing title of that book. I just checked the eight edition, it is a very good book, but I haven't found any summary table of expectations .

Comment: Have you checked the end of the book

Comment: I checked this one [here](http://julio.staff.ipb.ac.id/files/2015/02/Ross_8th_ed_English.pdf)

Comment: I see. You are right , there is no summary present . Anyway you may take a look at this book "Probability and Statistics "by Degroot

Comment: Another very good book! But not seen it [here](http://professor.ufabc.edu.br/~nelson.faustino/Ensino/IPE2016/Livros/Morris%20H%20DeGroot_%20Mark%20J%20Schervish-Probability%20and%20statistics-Pearson%20Education%20%20(2012)%20(1).pdf)

Comment: Go to page 853 (tables section)

Comment: Thanks. That one seems only based on specific distributions. I was asking for those on a wide variety of functions like $E[e^{-zR^{2}}]$ etc. some of which have been documented which can be easily referenced